# Adding NAPDEF on Nokia

Tags: mobile, oma, oma-dm

I am trying to add a new access point on a Nokia S60 device, but I am a little bitt puzzled on how to do it.
According to the [spec](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/b5a43a09-2d4b-4ea9-ad76-ecee12913ac7/OMA_DM_Management_Object_for_Connectivity_Settings_v1_1_en.pdf.html) a node should be added at the following root:

```
./AP/<X>
```

Whenever I try to add a node I get a status code 404 meaning that it could not be found. If I try to create an AP that already exists instead I get a status code 418 - it already exists.

The generated xml looks like this:

```
<Add>
  <CmdID>17</CmdID>
  <Item>
    <Target>
      <LocURI>./AP/testAP</LocURI>
    </Target>
    <Meta>
      <Format>node</Format>
      <Type>syncml:metinf</Type>
    </Meta>
  </Item>
</Add>
```

Using funambol I have also queried the whole ./AP tree and there exists a lot of access point already, all with names like APId00X.

I have tried using other names for my AP on the form APId00X with no luck either.

Does anyone know what it takes to create an AP on a S60 device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer in a post at Nokia Forum.

> [When trying to add an access point using a command ./AP/, it will fail with error 404 if some of the mandatory nodes are missing.](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/TSS000699_-_Adding_access_points_via_device_management)

So when adding an AP, it works fine as long as you remember to add all mandatory fields.
I'm not sure about which ones are the mandatory fields. I have succefully created an AP without Bearer, but I have not experimented with this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly an answer to your question but you might want to run some Symbian C++ code on the device to add the access point, if you can't find a way to do it successfully with OMA-DM.

If that works better, you may still be able to work around the problem by using OMA-DM to install the .sis file containing your code, run it and uninstall it.

It's ugly but there is a higher probability that Nokia actually tests each steps before releasing phones.